# How to create reusable component in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've started learning Vue.js and it's also my first experience in WebUI development, that why, I'm asking to sorry me if I tell or do something wrong.

Ok. I'm looking for a solution on how to create reusable components using this framework. I decide to create something like treeview with possibility of custom rendering of tree item.

Well, first of all, I decided to implement **treeview** component like this:

[image]

tree.vue.html

```
<template>
    <div class="clt">
        <ul v-if="hasRoots">
            <tree-item-component v-for="rootNode in rootNodes"
                                 :content="rootNode"
                                 :itemViewName="itemViewName"
                                 :key="rootNode.id"/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="./tree.ts"></script>
```

tree.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

import { ITreeItemContent } from './treeitem/treeitem'

@Component({
    components: {
        TreeItemComponent: require('./treeitem/treeitem.vue.html')
    },
    props: ['rootNodes', 'itemViewName', 'componentPath']
})
export default class TreeComponent extends Vue {
    rootNodes: ITreeItemContent[];
    itemViewName: string; // use this property to determine what component will be used to render tree item content

    get hasRoots(): boolean {
        return this.rootNodes && this.rootNodes.length > 0;
    }
};
```

treeitem.vue.html

```
<template>
    <li>
        <span v-if="hasSubNodes"
              @click="toggle">[{{isOpen ? '-' : '+'}}]</span>
        <span>
            <component v-if="itemViewName"
                       :is="itemViewName"
                       :itemData="itemData" />
        </span>
        <ul v-if="hasSubNodes" v-show="isOpen">
            <tree-item-component v-for="subNode in subNodes"
                                 :content="subNode"
                                 :itemViewName="itemViewName"
                                 :key="subNode.id" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
<script src="./treeitem.ts"></script>
```

treeitem.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

interface ITreeItemContent {
    id: number;
    itemData: any;
    subNodes: ITreeItemContent[];
}

@Component
export default class TreeItemComponent extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    content: ITreeItemContent;

    @Prop()
    itemViewName: string; // use this property to determine what component will be used to render content

    @Prop()
    componentnPath: string;

    isOpen: boolean = true;

    get hasSubNodes(): boolean {
        return this.subNodes && this.subNodes.length > 0;
    }

    get subNodes(): ITreeItemContent[] {
        return this.content.subNodes;
    }

    get itemData(): any {
        return this.content.itemData;
    }

    toggle(): void {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }
}

export { ITreeItemContent };
```

I register my component like this:

```
Vue.component('tree-component', require('./components/tree/tree.vue.html'));
```

Now I want to use it as a part of other components. I'm doing it this way:
[image]

categories.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { ITreeItemContent } from '../tree/treeitem/treeitem'
import { ITreeItemViewModel } from './treeitemview/treeitemview'

@Component({
    components: { // local registration of component what will be used to render tree item content
        TreeItemViewComponent: require('./treeitemview/treeitemview.vue.html')
    }
})
export default class CategoriesComponent extends Vue {
    itemViewName: string = 'tree-item-view-component';

    categories: ITreeItemContent[];

    data(): any {
        return { categories: testItemsData }
    }
}

let testItemsData: ITreeItemContent[] = [ /* test data */ ];
```

categories.vue.html

```
<template>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <tree-component :rootNodes="categories"
                        :itemViewName="itemViewName"></tree-component>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="./categories.ts"></script>
```

treeitemview.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

interface ITreeItemViewModel {
    msg: string;
    icon: string;
}

@Component
export default class TreeItemViewComponent extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    itemData: ITreeItemViewModel;

    get msg(): string {
        return this.itemData.msg;
    }

    get _class(): string {
        return 'glyphicon glyphicon-' + this.itemData.icon;
    }
}

export { ITreeItemViewModel };
```

treeitemview.vue.html

```
<template>
    <span :class="_class">{{msg}}</span>
</template>
<script src="./treeitemview.ts"></script>
```

I want to use `TreeItemViewComponent` as component what will display the content of node in **treeview** whats why, I registred it as local component for `CategoriesComponent` but then I run my code I catch an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <tree-item-view-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

If I register `TreeItemViewComponent` as global component like this:

```
Vue.component('tree-item-view-component', require('./components/categories/treeitemview/treeitemview.vue.html'));
```

everything work well. I read about component registration in Vue.js manual, but as I understand now, nested components don't know about localy registred components. In other words, if I register `TreeItemViewComponent` as local component for `CategoriesComponent` I can use `TreeItemViewComponent` only inside `CategoriesComponent` template. I've tried to pass `TreeItemViewComponent` component as property value for `TreeComponent` but I've got compilation errors.

I've also read about `$.refs` witch gives a possibility to access parent component inside child, but I don't understand how to use it.

The easiest solution is to register `TreeItemViewComponent` as global Vue.js component, but I think this is not right way, because of I want create multiple components what will use `TreeComponent` and provides their own `TreeItemViewComponent` and global registration of each `TreeItemViewComponent` will provide confusion in feature.

Do other solutions exist or it's impossible to create reusable components in Vue.js?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were almost there. I have not reviewed all of your code but I can tell you one thing I had to do to make Vuejs components work in Typescript.

Instead of: `TreeItemViewComponent: require('./treeitemview/treeitemview.vue.html')`

In Tree.ts use: `TreeItemViewComponent: Vue.component('tree-item-component', require('./treeitemview/treeitemview.vue.html'))`

Then in Tree.vue.html you can use `<tree-item-component></tree-item-component>`.